# Arena Reward Tiers

Tags: hearthstone

What are the tiers in arena for awards in Hearthstone?

When do you get 3 boxes, 4 boxes etc?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152683/arena-keys-and-corresponding-wins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arena rewards are not tied to the amount of boxes that are awarded to you; the amount of wins simply determines the range of rewards you are available to. Below you'll find a list, that describes the rewards that you could get (possible rewards), depending on the number of wins you were able to accumulate during a single arena run. Since it was part of your original question as well, I'll also include the number of boxes there.

- 0 wins / Novice (2 boxes): A pack, and either about 25-40 gold or dust, or a common card
- 1 win / Apprentice (2 boxes): A pack, and either about 30-50 gold or dust, or a common card
- 2 wins / Journeyman (2 boxes): A pack, and either about 40-50 gold or dust, or a common/rare card
- 3 wins / Copper (3 boxes): A pack and about 25-35 gold, plus either about 25 gold, about 25 dust, or a common/rare card
- 4 wins / Silver (3 boxes): A pack and about 45-60 gold, plus either about 25 gold, about 25 dust, or a common/rare card
- 5 wins / Gold (3 boxes): A pack and about 55 gold, plus either about 45-55 gold, about 45-50 dust, or a common/rare card
- 6 wins / Platinum (3-4 boxes): A pack and about 75-85 gold, plus one or two of: about 50-55 gold, about 50 dust, or a golden or regular common/rare card
- 7 wins / Diamond (3-4 boxes): A pack and about 150–160 gold, plus one or two of: about 30 gold, about 25 dust, golden or regular common/rare cards
- 8 wins / Champion (3-4 boxes): A pack and about 150-160 gold, plus one or two of: about 20-25 gold, about 25 dust, golden or regular common/rare/epic/legendary cards
- 9 wins / Ruby (3-4 boxes): A pack and about 155 gold, plus one or two of: about 75-95 gold, about 50 dust, golden or regular common/rare/epic/legendary cards
- 10 wins / Frostborn (3-4 boxes): A pack and about 175-185 gold, plus one or two of: about 70-115 gold, about 70-80 dust, golden common cards, golden or regular rare/epic/legendary cards
- 11 wins / Molten (3-4 boxes): A pack and about 195-210 gold, plus one or two of: about 80-180 gold, about 60-90 dust, golden common cards, golden or regular rare/epic/legendary cards
- 12 Wins / Lightforge (5 boxes): A pack and about 220-235 gold, plus three of: about 20-175 gold, about 20-25 dust, golden common cards, golden or regular rare/epic/legendary cards, additional card packs

There are various sources that could be cited, I'll cite the following:

http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Arena

Cheers mate.